# Use YouTube API to get Current Viewers of Scheduled Livestream

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In the YouTube web app livestreams that are scheduled for the future have a viewer count ("X Waiting") that shows the number of 'viewers' that are currently in the lobby waiting for the stream to start.

Normally this information is available through the videos list endpoint (under `liveStreamingDetails` as `concurrentViewers`) but it doesn't seem to be available for streams that haven't started yet.

Is there a way to get this information through the YouTube API?

Comment: Did you actually tested that [concurrentViewers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers) is not set while [liveBroadcastContent](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.liveBroadcastContent) is `upcoming`? As far as I see, `concurrentViewers` should be updated properly by the API when `liveBroadcastContent` is either `upcoming` or `live`.

Comment: @stvar here is an example stream that I am testing: HosH3O0MM1U. When I send the request to the video endpoint I get the following: `"liveStreamingDetails": {
    "scheduledStartTime": "2019-06-08T03:20:00.000Z",
    "scheduledEndTime": "2019-06-08T03:35:00.000Z",
    "activeLiveChatId": "Cg0KC0hvc0gzTzBNTTFV"
   }`

Comment: Yes, I see that indeed `concurrentViewers` isn't returned at all as part of the `liveStreamingDetails` object, while `liveBroadcastContent` is set to `upcoming`. But according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers), there is still the possibility that the broadcast owner has set that property hidden.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the docs are wrong though. The viewers are visible in the web app so I don't think they are hidden. Have you seen an example of an upcoming stream where the viewers are returned?

Comment: No, haven't seen one; also true that I did not paid attention to that detail. On the other hand, you could report this issue to [Google](https://issuetracker.google.com). Unfortunately, though, is that since about two months now, the staff stopped taking into consideration any issue [raised](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I have reported a few other bugs to them and haven't gotten much response :/ I appreciate your help in looking at this issue though!

Comment: @xokocodo is good you did reported bugs to them. Keep looking its status, though. Eventually they'll answer - mostly "won't fix" but, at least, you did the right thing.